# Line Following Robot using PID control not working

Tags: robotics

I'm currently making a line following robot using PID control. My robot uses an Arduino Uno board, a L298N motor, 1 9V battery, 2 motors, 5 TCRT 5000 infrared light sensors to detect a black line on a white surface. I uploaded the code successfully but my robot didn't do anything:

- Both of my motors didn't run at all
- the sensors couldn't detect the line. The sensors somehow could only detect the distance between it and the ground when i lift the robot above the ground.
- The wire connections are fine.
  When i used a multimeter to measure the voltage, I found out that there was no voltage from the L298N to both motors. The circuit diagram that i'm using:
  [![enter image description here][6]][6]

And this is my code:

```
float Kp = 1;
float Ki = 1;
float Kd = 1;

//setup speed of the motors
#define ENAspeed 200
#define ENBspeed 200

#define ENB 5 // Enable pin PWM of the Left motor
#define IN4 6 // pin of left motor
#define IN3 7 // pin of left motor
#define IN2 8 // pin of right motor
#define IN1 9 // pin of right motor
#define ENA 10 // Enable pin PWM of the Right motor

int Sensor[] = {A1, A2, A3, A4, A5};
float P = 0;
float I = 0;
float D = 0;
int Error = 0;

int Previous_Error, Previous_I;
int PID_value;
int Left_Speed, Right_Speed;

void setup(){
    
     pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
     
     pinMode(A1, INPUT);
     pinMode(A2, INPUT);
     pinMode(A3, INPUT);
     pinMode(A4, INPUT);
     pinMode(A5, INPUT);
     
     digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
     digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
     digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH);
     digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
     
     analogWrite(ENB, Left_Speed);
     analogWrite(ENA, Right_Speed);

     for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
      {Sensor[i];}
     // reading the sensor if HIGH (Black line) or LOW (White line) line
     Sensor[1] = digitalRead(A1);
     Sensor[2] = digitalRead(A2);
     Sensor[3] = digitalRead(A3);
     Sensor[4] = digitalRead(A4);
     Sensor[5] = digitalRead(A5);
}

    void loop() {
    //use analogwrite to run motor at adjusted speed
     CalculateError();
     Calculate_PID();
     motor_control();
}
                                                                                                                                                                 
  void CalculateError(){
  if ((Sensor[1] == 1) && (Sensor[2] == 0) && (Sensor[3] == 0) && (Sensor[4] == 0) && (Sensor[5] == 0))  
  {Error = 4;}
  else if ((Sensor[1] == 1) && (Sensor[2] == 1) && (Sensor[3] == 0) && (Sensor[4] == 0) && (Sensor[5] == 0)) 
  {Error = 3;}
  else if ((Sensor[1] == 0) && (Sensor[2] == 1) && (Sensor[3] == 0) && (Sensor[4] == 0) && (Sensor[5] == 0)) 
  {Error = 2;}
  else if ((Sensor[1] == 0) && (Sensor[2] == 1) && (Sensor[3] == 1) && (Sensor[4] == 0) && (Sensor[5] == 0)) 
  {Error = 1;}
  else if ((Sensor[1] == 0) && (Sensor[2] == 0) && (Sensor[3] == 1) && (Sensor[4] == 0) && (Sensor[5] == 0)) 
  {Error = 0;}
  else if ((Sensor[1] == 0) && (Sensor[2] == 0) && (Sensor[3] == 1) && (Sensor[4] == 1) && (Sensor[5] == 0)) 
  {Error = -1;}
  else if ((Sensor[1] == 0) && (Sensor[2] == 0) && (Sensor[3] == 0) && (Sensor[4] == 1) && (Sensor[5] == 0)) 
  {Error = -2;}
  else if ((Sensor[1] == 0) && (Sensor[2] == 0) && (Sensor[3] == 0) && (Sensor[4] == 1) && (Sensor[5] == 1)) 
  {Error = -3;}  
  else if ((Sensor[1] == 0) && (Sensor[2] == 0) && (Sensor[3] == 0) && (Sensor[4] == 0) && (Sensor[5] == 1)) 
  {Error = -4;}
  //Special case
  else if ((Sensor[1] == 0) && (Sensor[2] == 0) && (Sensor[3] == 0) && (Sensor[4] == 0) && (Sensor[5] == 0))
  {if (Previous_Error = -4) {Error = -5;}
  else if (Previous_Error = 4) {Error = 5;}} 
  else if ((Sensor[1] == 1) && (Sensor[2] == 1) && (Sensor[3] == 1) && (Sensor[4] == 1) && (Sensor[5] == 1))
  {Error = 0;}
}

  void Calculate_PID() { 
    P = Error;
    I += Error;
    //I = I + Previous_I;
    D = Error - Previous_Error;

    PID_value = (Kp * P) + (Ki * I) + (Kd * D);

    I += Error;
    Previous_I = I;
    Previous_Error = Error;
}

  void motor_control() {
     
     //define new speed limitation for the engine
     Left_Speed  = constrain (Left_Speed, 0, 255);
     Right_Speed = constrain(Right_Speed, 0, 255);
     
     //calculating the effective motor speed:
          if ((-5 < Error) and (Error < 0)){
              Left_Speed  = ENBspeed - PID_value;
              Right_Speed = ENAspeed + PID_value;
          }

          if ((0 < Error) and (Error < 5)){
              Left_Speed  = ENBspeed + PID_value;
              Right_Speed = ENAspeed - PID_value;
          }

          if (Error == 0){
              Left_Speed  = ENBspeed;
              Right_Speed = ENAspeed;
          }
     }
```

Sorry for my bad English if there is any mistake. I'm quite new to Arduino and thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `9V battery` ... if this is a regular block battery, then it is only good in very low current applications, such as smoke alarms

Comment: so should i use a 4 AA battery instead? Thanks for your recommmadation.

Comment: `Both of my motors didn't run at all` ... it is pointless to even look at your code ... first, make sure that you can control **one** motor ... write a simple sketch to run one motor, in one direction, for one second, pause one second, then repeat .... then run opposite direction .... then run two motors .... each time use a simple sketch that does only one thing ........ then move to sensors .... light up an LED to indicate that the sensor is detecting a line, nothing more ... when all components work, then move to combining the components

Comment: what voltage do 4 AA cells produce?

Comment: Yes, maybe i should slow down and try to do it step by step. 4AA cells if connected in series then it'll produce a 6V output. Is that the answer you're looking for?

Comment: i am not saying that you need to slow down ... i am saying that you need to test the hardware first ... at this point, you do not know if the problem is caused by hardware, or by software ... about the AA cells, i just qanted to make sure that you were aware of the voltage, because you said that you ate using a 9 V battery .... anyway, since you probably have everything connected, try replacing the battery before you start testing motors and sensors ... you may actually have everything already working, only power starved

Comment: LOL I guess problem solved. I did like what you'd suggested and turns out, the hardware, software, wire connections are fine. The robot doesn't move due to the 9V battery. The motors did spin but didn't provide enough force to move the robot. Thanks for your help, i'll use 4AA cells instead.